# Is this a legitimate way to make a non-measurable set?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I thought up a way of creating a non-measurable set, and I'd appreciate some input. Thanks!

Let $G$ be a countable group acting on an uncountable measure space $X: \mu(X)<\infty, |X|=\aleph$. Let's assume that $\exists A \subseteq X: \mu(A)\neq 0$ and $A$ is a subset of the set of the representatives of the orbits of $G$ on $X$. Let's define $V$ as the set of representatives of the orbits, such that $A\subseteq V\subseteq X$. Therefore, $0<\mu(A)\leq \mu(V) \leq \mu(X)<\infty$.

Let's write $G=(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, and let's define $V_n=V+g_n$, such that $V_n$ is also a set of representatives, and $V_n\cap V_m=\emptyset, A\subseteq \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}V_n\subseteq X$, such that $0<\mu(A)\leq \mu(\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}V_n)\leq\mu(X)<\infty$. Since $V_n$ are all disjoint sets, then $\mu(\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}V_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(V_n)$, and therefore:

$0<\mu(A)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(V_n) \leq \mu(X)<\infty$.

On the other hand, $\mu(V_n)=\mu(V)$, and therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(V_n)$ must be $0$, if $\mu(V)=0$, which obviously cannot be, or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(V_n)=\infty$, if $\mu(V)>0$, such that we get a contradiction, and therefore, $V$ isn't measurable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are assuming the action of $G$ has no fixed point. You used that when you say $V_n \cap V_m = \emptyset$. Assuming that, I think the idea is correct and is a generalization of finding a non-measurable set in e.g. $[0,1]$. Actually you do not need $A$. You used axiom of choice to find a $V$. Then if $V$ is non-measurable, you are done.

So you can assume $V$ to be measureable, then $\mu(V)\neq 0$ as $\bigcup V_n = X$ and $\mu(V_n) = \mu(V)$. Using your argument then again you come up with the contradiction.